# how to pass value to contract via php (no java script)?

Tags: contract-development, php

I wrote a contract that get a unit and do something

**My question :**

How to pass a value to this contract function via **PHP**? (not js,py,MetaMask, ... . just in php)

For example, I use [this](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki) and install success in my Ubuntu server and run

```
geth account new
```

and get the result.

But I don't know how to use next step (Developer/Management API).

Please describe a real example by details with **any packages** or something that familer for you from how to install package on Ubuntu server and a simple contract that get a value and write a PHP file that if I run in my Lampp, send a value to my contract

> I saw a lot of same question in google, but most of them done with js
>   or in short form in PHP and I cant figure out
>
> I'm new in use GitHub and Composer.JSON files

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SE! Check out the https://github.com/sc0Vu/web3.php project.

Their examples can help you out in achieving this in PHP.

```
// example
use Web3\Contract;

$contractABI = '[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]';

$contract = new Contract('http://localhost:8545', $contractABI);

$contractAddress = "0x9f8f72aa9304c8b593d555f12ef6589cc3a579a2";

// call contract function
$contract->at($contractAddress)->call("name", null, function($data) {
    echo "received name" + $data;
});
```

Hope this helps.